# Add amount to cart line item

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce4

On the "add to cart" page, I let the user enter "Width" & "Length" to calculate the number of Square Foot as the quantity which works fine with a JS function. Now my client wants to add an "overhead" price to the product based on the selected variations. Is there a way, either an "hidden field" in the form OR a hook in the module where I can put the amount to add to the line item ?
Or any other best idea is appreciated as well !
I'm on Craft Commerce 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change the price of the line item based on the option data sent in.

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/dynamically-customizing-line-item-prices

Comment: The worst thing is that you cannot change the total and subtotal, as this is a property read, except adjusters.

Comment: Thanks @Luke for your answer. You pointed me at the right place. However, from what I see, it looks like all the previous line-items are visited in the process. Althought the rules don't change, it will perform calc on already saved items. 
Is there a way to get a hook on the actual item added to the cart ?